# c++ program which gets the currency rates from webpage

Tags: c++

Hi i want to write a program in C++ that would get live rates from Google or Yahoo or some other web page and then perform the conversion. Can someone guide me how to go about this?

Comment: Here's your guide:  Search the internet for libraries that obtain present currency rate.  Include them in your project.  Read the API or documentation to figure out how to use them.  Try something like "currency conversion library c++ google".  Or contact Google directly.

Comment: This is called "scraping".  All you need to do is periodically access the page, and parse the data out.  Using C++ for this seems like overkill.  Unfortunately, your question is a little too broad.  You haven't identified a specific area that you're having trouble with.  If you could narrow it down, show what you have tried and ask a specific question you might have better luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
CSocket r;
wchar_t ku[5100];

AfxSocketInit();

 wchar_t b[]=L"GET /currency-converter/#from=USD;to=EUR;amt=1 H
TTP/1.1\r\nhost:finance.yahoo.com\r\n\r\n";

;
    r.Create()
    r.Connect(L"finance.yahoo.com",80);
    r.Send(b,sizeof(b));
    r.Receive(ku,sizeof(ku));  //header stuff
    r.Receive(ku,sizeof(ku));  //rate
    CString t(ku); 
    //grabbed data is ready
```

Pros: CString + WSA error stuff

And linux sample:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
 #include <unistd.h> 
       #include <netdb.h>
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char  server_reply[5000];

     struct hostent *host;

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");
     host = gethostbyname("finance.yahoo.com");


    server.sin_addr.s_addr=*((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");


char        message[]="GET /currency-converter/#from=USD;to=EUR;amt=1 HTTP/1.1\r\nhost:finance.yahoo.com\r\n\r\n";

        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }


        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 3000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");

        }

        puts("Server reply :");

        puts(server_reply);



        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 3000 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");

        }
         puts(server_reply);


    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite broad. 
Few major steps could be defined as below:

1. You could create a socket to a particular website and stream that data from that website. For more information on this, you could check- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/iostreams.html
2. Then you can scan the data and write regular expressions in order to retrieve the value from the data and then output them wherever you want to display.

Then you can write a bash script to run this code object again and again on regular intervals. Hence you would have live results without scanning the website manually.